# Непонятки с CSS под мобильные браузеры

Tags: android, css, orientation

День добрый. 
Возникло непонимание, а как вообще работает цсс с мобильными устройствами? Например, есть такая ЦССка

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


#content {

    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;


    background-image: url(back.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;

}


#p1080{

    position: absolute;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -960px;
    margin-top: -540px;



    border: 4px double black;

}

#p720{

    position: absolute;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 720px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -640px;
    margin-top: -360px;

    border: 2px solid red;

}

#p360{

    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -320px;
    margin-top: -180px;

    border: 2px solid blue;

}
```

Которая под виндой прекрасно центруется без всяких проблем.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот на мобильнике (1920*1080) начинается что-то, мне непонятное: Например, в ландшафтной ориентации[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Или в портретной: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Разве не должно центроваться так же, как в обычном браузере? Ткните пожалуйста носом, что почитать и как понять.

Заранее признателен.

Comment: meta viewport?.

Comment: То есть, я правильно понимаю, что не определив размер вьюпорта, к реальным пикселям разрешения экрана, я не прицеплюсь никак? Так же как и к процентам?

Comment: Во вьюпорт можно прописать width=device-width